# Send a collection of objects to a Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My controller:

```
        IList<OrderRow> emailOrders = ParseIncomingEmails();
        return View("ImportEmailedOrders.cshtml", emailOrders);
```

My aspx page allows me to iterate with:
    foreach (OrderRow orderRow in Model)

I've tried various combinations of '@inherits' and '@model ....' directives without finding the correct syntax to achieve the same looping mechanism for a Razor view.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to put

```
@model IList<OrderRow>
```

at the top of your page.

Is the problem that you dont have the fully qualified namespace for OrderRow?

i.e.

```
@model IList<Namespace.OrderRow>
```

You can add the namespace in the web config like

```
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
            <add namespace="MyMvcProject.Namespace"/>
        </namespaces>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
@model IList<OrderRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this declaration in the beginning of the page

```
@model IList<OrderRow>
```

and you can iterate on model

```
@foreach(var item in model)
{
  //do something
}
```